# It's possible to use Nativescript-photo-editor in ionic project

Tags: angular, ionic3, nativescript

i m new in *ionic* and i would like to use `Nativescript-photo-editor plugin` in my *ionic* *angular 6* project. This plugin can be used with *angular* so I would to know if It's possible to use in my project

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you try and see if it works?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which one you are referring to while mentioning ionic. Is it mobile app (integrated with Cordova) or ionic web app.

The answer will be no in both cases, Cordova uses its own plugin architecture so {N} plugins can't be used with Cordova. But you might be able to write a photo editor plugin for Cordova with same features by implementing a Cordova plugin with the same native dependencies used in the {N} plugin.

Web apps are totally different, there is no way you could get iOS / Android libraries to work on Web.